# Operators not working on if else condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am receiving data via ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajax_url,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { action: 'data_savedInternal', id: saveThis}
    success: function(data) {
        if( data["found"] = "no"  ) {
            console.log(data["count"]);
            if(parseInt(data["count"]) <= 2) {
                //do something...
            } else {
                //do something else ...
            }
        }
```

`console.log(data["count"]);` gives `2` and it should go to `else` but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing assignment apart from comparison:

So change

```
if( data["found"] = "no"  ) {
```

to

```
 if( data["found"] == "no"  ) {
```

According to me `<=` needs to be worked in case if `data["count"] < 2` or `data["count"] == 2` (according to `<=` documentation)

What seems to me is datatype mismatch causes a loophole in it(Although i am not sure)

So kindly check once

```
if(parseInt(data["count"]) < 2 || parseInt(data["count"]) === 2) {
    //do something...
} else {
    //do something else ...
}
```

But for me the best and more efficient answer is:-

```
if(parseInt(data["count"]) > 2) {
    //do something else ...
} else {
    //do something...
}
```

Comment: I never asked to check if it's 2 in the question, I need to check if the value from json is equal or less

Comment: yes it did work as suggested. What I don't understand is why. If I say check if in the box are 2 or less, should I not use <= ?

Comment: yes and true should take me to the if not the else but it is taking me to else if I use <= 2 but I do have 2 tho

Comment: right so it's like asking check it it's less than itself

Comment: Basically to my mind "less than or" means either 1,999999 and below or the actual 2. So <= is correct. But apparently not.

Comment: `or exactly equals to 2` and that's my point, `console.log(data["count"]);` gives `2` so `<=` should work

Comment: @rob.m  i have updated my answer along with everything what i know... I don't know the very exact reason what's not working at your end.

Comment: @rob.m Also in your question itself you wrote `console.log(data["count"]) gives 2 and it should go to `else` but it's not.-> because `2<=2` is true and it will go for `if` part and that's it from my side. No more chat i can do now. Completely exhausted

Comment: `if(parseInt(data["count"]) < 2 || parseInt(data["count"]) === 2) {` ok so I just got offended by many and down voted, question closed for free. Because my doubt is correct and I was not wrong.

Comment: basically the issue is somewhere else not in my logic.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use triple equals for this to work. Single equals simple assigns the value to the left hand side

```
if( data["found"] === "no"  ) {
```

Also remove the equals from

```
if(parseInt(data["count"]) <= 2) {
```

to

```
if(parseInt(data["count"]) === 2) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(parseInt(data["count"]) <= 2) {
```

In javascript, `<=` indicates **less than or equals**, so instead of `<=`, use `<`:

```
if(parseInt(data["count"]) < 2) {
```

Here is your code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajax_url,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { action: 'data_savedInternal', id: saveThis}
    success: function(data) {
        if( data["found"] = "no"  ) {
            console.log(data["count"]);
            if(parseInt(data["count"]) < 2) {
                ... do something...
            } else {
                ... do something else ...
            }
        }
```

Comment: I never asked to check if it's 2 in the question, I need to check if the value from json is equal or less